Is it possible to install the Google Cloud CLI on alpine Linux Without it installing a bundled version of python?
Problem Background
I am building an Alpine Linux docker image to use as a (relatively) lightweight CI image. In this image, I need to have the Google Cloud gcloud CLI installed.
I am installing Python from my Dockerfile like this:
RUN apk add python3

On Alpine Linux 3.20, (on 2024/12/03,) this installs Python 3.12.7. Installing some version of python appears to be a pre-requisite for even running the Google Cloud CLI install script.
/ # cat /etc/alpine-release 
3.20.0
/ # python --version
Python 3.12.7

Google Cloud CLI claims to be compatible with Python 3.8 to 3.13 - source, under the "Linux" tab.
I am installing the Google Cloud CLI using a script like this, run from inside my container being built:
mkdir -p /usr/local/gcloud
curl -s https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/release/google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz | tar -xz -C /usr/local/gcloud
/usr/local/gcloud/google-cloud-sdk/install.sh --quiet --usage-reporting false

When I run this script as part of my Docker image build, I see this:
#17 8.452 Your current Google Cloud CLI version is: 502.0.0
#17 8.452 Installing components from version: 502.0.0
#17 8.452
#17 8.495 ┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
#17 8.495 │                     These components will be installed.                     │
#17 8.496 ├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────┬────────────┬──────────┤
#17 8.496 │                         Name                        │  Version   │   Size   │
#17 8.497 ├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼────────────┼──────────┤
#17 8.497 │ BigQuery Command Line Tool                          │      2.1.9 │  1.7 MiB │
#17 8.499 │ BigQuery Command Line Tool (Platform Specific)      │      2.1.8 │  < 1 MiB │
#17 8.501 │ Bundled Python 3.11 (Platform Specific)             │     3.11.9 │ 74.4 MiB │
#17 8.503 │ Cloud Storage Command Line Tool                     │       5.31 │ 11.3 MiB │
#17 8.504 │ Cloud Storage Command Line Tool (Platform Specific) │       5.30 │  < 1 MiB │
#17 8.506 │ Google Cloud CLI Core Libraries (Platform Specific) │ 2024.08.30 │  < 1 MiB │
#17 8.507 │ Google Cloud CRC32C Hash Tool (Platform Specific)   │      1.0.0 │  1.3 MiB │
#17 8.509 │ gcloud cli dependencies (Platform Specific)         │ 2021.04.16 │  < 1 MiB │
#17 8.510 └─────────────────────────────────────────────────────┴────────────┴──────────┘

The line that caught my eye is the ~75MiB "Bundled Python 3.11" line. I would like to prevent the installer script from downloading and using a Bundled version of Python. Is this possible?
Things I've Tried
--install-python false Flag
When I run the --help on the script to see options, one catches my eye:
/usr/local/gcloud/google-cloud-sdk/install.sh --help

# ....
  --install-python INSTALL_PYTHON
                        (true/false) Attempt to install Python. MacOS only.

Sure enough, this flag appears to not do anything on Alpine Linux (I still see the install script downloading and installing Python 3.11).
Setting CLOUDSDK_PYTHON environment variable
After some Googling around, I attempted to set the CLOUDSDK_PYTHON environment variable  in my Dockerfile in two ways:
ENV CLOUDSDK_PYTHON="/usr/bin/python"
ENV CLOUDSDK_PYTHON="/usr/bin/python3"

Neither worked (I still see the install script downloading and installing Python 3.11).
Not a solution for me: Google Provided Docker Container
I understand that Google provides a base image that already has the gcloud CLI installed. For reasons that aren't fully relevant to the main thrust of this question, I can't use that to elide this problem. I have to use a different Alpine Linux based base image.

Looks like you can install gcloud in a separate stage to avoid it touching your python installation? That way you can just copy the gcloud installation (may be slightly tricky) into your final image.

@DiegoMarquez that's a great point - I saw a similar trick for Node.js here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76132347/1473320
For the purposes of this question, I'd like to know if there's a way to do it using the traditional installer.

Fair enough. I took a look at the docs and found this part interesting: "Note that the x86_64 Linux package includes a bundled Python interpreter that will be preferred by default.
I guess that means that the x86 version (which btw is half the size of the x86_64 version) will not force that bundled python version in your final image? - edit, I'm positive this may do the trick so I'll leave it as an answer

Following/copying from my comment.
I took a look at the docs and found this part interesting: "Note that the x86_64 Linux package includes a bundled Python interpreter that will be preferred by default.
The x86 version (which btw is half the size of the x86_64 version) will not force that bundled python version in your final image.
Condensed from docs:
curl -O https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/downloads/google-cloud-cli-linux-x86.tar.gz && \
tar -xf google-cloud-cli-linux-x86.tar.gz && \
./google-cloud-sdk/install.sh

